# Apply settings from edited eclipse epf file

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, epf

we exported eclipse settings in an epf file. Afterwards we change the encoding setting and exported another epf file. The diff shows us only one setting:

/instance/org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding=UTF-8

When we try to import this setting into eclipse the encoding doesn't change and in the import dialog there is an error message shown:

Empty list.

Note: Not all preferences support individual import.

Does anybody know how to find out which preferences belongs together?

We need to have stripped down epf files, because we only want to change specific settings.

regards
Andreas

Comment: Probably determined by the preference transfer classes defined using the `org.eclipse.ui.preferenceTransfer` extension point. You would probably have to read the source to work it out.

Comment: Thx Greg for the hint with the extension point! I feared,that it's not as simple as finding some configuration files with a readable xml structure for exported data :-(